# how to get postal code with react-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, google-api, next.js

I have a search bar with the Google Maps Places Autocomplete.
I am using the npm package 'react-places-autocomplete' in Next.js.

Is there any way to get the postal code in handleSelect?

```
import { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from 'react-places-autocomplete';

export default function CP({...}: Props) {
 

  const handleSelect = async (address) => {
    const results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
    const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
  };


  return (
      <LocationSearchInput
        address={state.address}
        visible={visible}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleSelect={handleSelect}
      />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I get the postal code:

```
import { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng, geocodeByPlaceId } from 'react-places-autocomplete';

  const handleSelect = async (address, placeId) => {
    const results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
    const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
    const [place] = await geocodeByPlaceId(placeId);
    const { long_name: postalCode = '' } =
      place.address_components.find(c => c.types.includes('postal_code')) || {};
    console.log("postalCode",postalCode);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer: No, you can't directly get the postcode from the google places autocomplete service** you can see the [response object here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletePrediction)

**Long answer: Yes with more calls.**

In the prediction you will be given a property called a `place_id`, you can use this with other google services such as [getDetails](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.getDetails) which will provide you with a [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult) where you can get address details such as lat and lng coordinates.

If you still can't get the address details you need this point you can use free a service like https://postcodes.io/ to then get the postcode from the lat and lng coordinates.

I have a full guide on [how you can use postcodes with the JavaScript Google Places Api here](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/javascript/how-to-get-postcodes-from-google-places-and-google-maps/)

---

As for **react-places-autocomplete**:

I am not sure what it provides but if the module is anything like **[use-places-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@atomap/use-places-autocomplete)**, an easier solution would be to get the place_id from the prediction, use next.js's ssr capability and make the above requests server side and then return the postcode to your client side.

**If you want to know any more about using the Google Places Autocomplete Service with react I suggest taking a look at this blog post/tutorial** that I wrote about it: https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/react/how-to-use-google-autocomplete-with-react-hooks/